# Distributive lattice and embedding

Tags: logic, order-theory, lattice-orders

Good evening everybody,

I am working on the notion of lattice, which is still very difficult for me to grasp.
I have this question:

Suppose that a lattice T can be embedded in a distributive lattice D. Show that T is also distributive.

It is my understanding that an embedding conserves the operations, so if T has ∧,∨, so does D. Then I could verify the distributivity of T by seeing if this is true: 
x ∧ (y ∨ z) = (x ∧ y) ∨ (x ∧ z)

But then, how am I suppose to do so without any value to verify if it works? Or maybe I'm having a completely wrong angle for this problem? (It's very possible, I'm new to this and completely outside of my field of study.)

Any help would be appreciated,

Thank you

Comment: Part of your problem seems to be that "embedding conserves the operations" means a lot more than you said. If $e:T\to D$ is an embedding, then it satisfies $e(x)\land_De(y)=e(x\land_Ty)$ (where the subscripts indicate which lattice's $\land$ is meant) and similarly for $\lor$.

Comment: Thank you for the precision! I understand that for an embedding f, f (a ∧ b) = f (a)∧f(b)  and f (a ∨ b) = f(a)∨f(b). But then, how can I prove the transitivity? My problem is mostly related with the way we can construct a formal proof

Comment: This is a universal and formal principle in Algebra: At first you should write down the law that you want to prove in $D$, but you express the elements as images of the embedding $e$ , e.g. $e(x) \wedge_D e(y)$. Then you can pull out $e$ interatively by applying the “embedding conserves the operations” law whereever it is possible, in the example you get $e(x\wedge_Ty)$. You have to be very strinct. After each step you get new opportunities. And finally you get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is: Distributivity can be (theoretically) destroyed by a single counter example. Embedding means injectivity: if $x\neq y$ then $e(x)\neq e(y)$. So if an equation has a counterexample in $T$ it also has a counterexample in $D$.

This can be used formally to describe a direct proof. To avoid unnecessary spoilers, suppose I want to prove that every groupoid (set with a binary operation) that embeds into a semigroup is already a semigroup. So we have two operations $*$ in $T$ and $\cdot$ in $D$. And we know that $D$ is associative. In a first step I write down the associative law in $D$: $$x_D\cdot(y_D \cdot z_D) = (x_D\cdot y_D)\cdot z_D.$$
(This line does not need to occur in the proof, it is only for the construction of the proof).

Now I replace every variable by the embedding of an element of $T$:
$$e(x)\cdot\bigl(e(y)\cdot e(z)\bigr)=\bigl(e(x)\cdot e(y)\bigr)\cdot e(z).$$
The embedding $e$ supports the equation $e(x*y) = e(x)\cdot e(y)$. We apply this to the inner parentheses (the outer operation does not support it, yet):
$$e(x)\cdot e\bigl(y *  z\bigr)=e(x)\cdot\bigl(e(y)\cdot e(z)\bigr)=\bigl(e(x)\cdot e(y)\bigr)\cdot e(z)=e\bigl(x * y\bigr)\cdot e(z)$$

Now, also the outer operations have the structure that allows us to apply the law again:
$$e\bigl(x * (y *  z)\bigr)=e(x)\cdot e\bigl(y *  z\bigr)=e\bigl(x * y\bigr)\cdot e(z)=e\bigl((x * y) *z\bigr)$$

Finally, we apply that $e$ is injective, which implies
$$x * (y *  z)=(x * y) *z$$
q.e.d.

As you can see it is a very formal process. In the same way you can prove your distributivity law. I chose a different example, here as you obviously need some exercise with this method.

Comment: Thank you so much! How is this? 

I know this is true in D:  x ∧ (y ∨ z) = (x ∨ y) ∨ (x ∧ z) 
Now I replace all the variables with an embedding of an element of T

 e (x) ∧ (e (y) ∨ e(z)) = (e (x) ∨ e(y)) ∨ (e (x) ∧ e(z))  

Since the embedding e supports those equalities: (∧) = () ∧ () and 
e (x∧y) = e(x) ∧ e(y), I can start to do substitutions, so we have

e (x) ∧ e (y ∨ z) = e (x ∨ y) ∨ e (y ∧ z)  

and e (x ∧ (y ∨ z)  = e ((x ∨ y) ∨ (y ∧ z))

and then we apply e to have:  x ∧ (y ∨ z) = (x ∨ y) ∨ (y ∧ z)

Comment: The last step is not applying e, but using the fact that the mapping is an embedding meaning $x \neq y ⇒ e(x) \neq e(y)$ which leads to the rule $e(x) = e(y) ⇔ x = y$.